# Looping over existing colours in addplot in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, color, foreach

In [Change color in addplot in for loop of pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305175/change-color-in-addplot-in-for-loop-of-pgfplots) It was discussed how to loop over nonexistent colours in `\addplot` and `axis` I would however like to loop over existing colours, but:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{greyscale1}{rgb}{0.1,0.1,0.1}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \foreach \file in {1}
    \addplot[color=greyscale\file] table [col sep=comma] {d.dat};;
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

returns the error:

```
Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `greyscale\file '.
```

If instead I do:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{greyscale1}{rgb}{0.1,0.1,0.1}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \file in {1}
    \draw[color=greyscale\file] (0,2) -- (1,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get:

[image]

## Edit:

d.dat looks like

```
0,2
1,2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the usual expansion issues. One way to go here is to use `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach`.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{d.dat}
0,2
1,2
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{greyscale1}{rgb}{0.1,0.1,0.1}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ymin=1.8,ymax=2.2]
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1}
    {\addplot[color={greyscale#1}] table [col sep=comma] {d.dat};}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yup, I found out ;-) While this works for having to loop over *1* variable the answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170670/125223 is needed to loop over more. Unless you can do something cool with `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach`

Comment: @ThorbjørnE.K.Christensen The answer in your link also has just one argument, but if you want several, look at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17817/121799) by the author of pgfplots. These expansion issues are not limited to `\foreach`, i.e. there are several other situations in which you may want to do `\edef\temp{\noexpand\addplot ...}  \temp` but here you do not need it.