# Command used to plot only keeps last value of macro

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, macros

I am trying to define a command that prints a plot and a given calculated parameter of a plot each time that command is called. When this command is run more than once the parameter in question keeps only the last value assigned to it. See below for functioning example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgflibrary{fpu}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}


\newcommand{\UoneCurveInst}[2]{
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\LT}{#2/#1}            
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
    \addplot[no markers,forget plot]coordinates{(#2,70) (#2,100)} node[above,xshift=-.1cm,yshift=-.75cm,pos=0,rotate=45] {\color{black}#2A:\LT};    
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{loglogaxis}[title= TCC Curve,xlabel= {Current (A)},grid=both,
            ylabel= {Time (seconds)},log ticks with fixed point,xmin=100,xmax=100000,ymin=0.01,ymax=100,
            xticklabel style={rotate=90, anchor=east, /pgf/number format/fixed,/pgf/number format/precision = 0},
            xtick={100,1000,10000,100000},height=9in, width=7in]            
            \UoneCurveInst{120}{800}
            \UoneCurveInst{120}{600}
        \end{loglogaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}\
```

I only recently started using this kind of macro so I feel I am missing something about their fundamental function.

Edit: the specific problem I am having is that both of the instances of the use of `\LT` output the same value but they should be different. The value of `\LT` is used for both plots is whatever the last calculated value is.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Thank you for providing a minimal example, but I'm having a problem understanding what's wrong with it.  Can you give us a little more text to explain what you're expecting to happen, as opposed to what is actually happening?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Need to expand it out e.g. [foreach - Change color in addplot in for loop of pgfplots - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305175/change-color-in-addplot-in-for-loop-of-pgfplots) / [pgfplots: use foreach inside addplot - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264168/pgfplots-use-foreach-inside-addplot). There's also a note at the end of page 546 of pgfplots documentation but it will probably only make sense to you if you know TeX programming